# Unable to set "style property" in GTK3

Tags: css, c, properties, gtk

I am trying to set widgets' style properties (coding with C on windows) but it doesn't work:

I tried putting in in the css file

```
* {
    -GtkButton-child-displacement-y: 20;
}
```

and it didn't work, I also tried setting it inside the xml file adding this property to a GtkButton

```
<property name='child-displacement-y'>20</property>
```

an it doesn't work (invalide property) I suppose style properties can't be set along with properties

So, what am I doing wrong? why the css file ignores widget specific style properties ?

(GTK+ version 3.18 on windows)

Comment: It seems that the property lacks the units, try appending *px* to `20`. Also, you can do it directly with [tag:c] code instead of setting it here, but of course it is preferrable to do it like you want because it's more maintainable.

Comment: style properties don't take units, this one takes a `gint` or `guint`
(and it doesn't work even if I add `px`)

Comment: Are you sure, that is a [tag:c] type for *glib*, css might work a little different. What does the documentation say?

Comment: yes I can use `gint` fine in the .c file, since I am including Gtk libraries,,
the documentation says to use a style property you just do `-namespace-styleproperty: value;` in the css file, but it doesn't work

Comment: How did you load the CSS file?

Comment: `provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
    display = gdk_display_get_default ();
    screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen (display);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen (screen, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER (provider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);

    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path (provider,"style.css",NULL);
    g_object_unref (provider);`

Answer (score 0):

`GtkButton::child-displacement-y` is now ignored as of GTK+ 3.20. Your CSS won't work anymore anyway. It may have already been broken in 3.18. Sorry. :/ The documentation suggests using CSS margins and padding instead.

That being said, otherwise your CSS is correct. I presume you simply are not loading it correctly. You can't just drop a random .css file and expect it to work; you need to explicitly load it using GtkCssProvider into a GtkStyleContext (either one that belongs to a widget or to the default GdkScreen to have it apply to all widgets). (If you are instead modifying the theme file directly, then see the first paragraph.)

Comment: I am loading the CSS file with the css provider, display and screen ... and It's not just about the child-displacement-y , it's about ALL the widget style properties, they do not work..
Also the margins in CSS doesn't work in GTK 3.18.6 .... :/

Comment: @RedStar It took a while for widgets to be converted across to the new "CSS gadget"/"indirect" rendering model, which is what makes CSS margins and so on work at all. Most of the typical widgets should work now, but if you still find any that don't, then file a bug (and maybe even submit a patch!) requesting to have it converted.